# Php javascript encoding issue

Tags: javascript, php, utf-8

I am using following encoding on the start of my php page

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');
```

I also use

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'>
```

latter in the code

The line that makes me the problem is

```
 echo "<span  onclick=\"alert('".$translated_word."');alert('".$value."'); \" >".$value." </span>";
```

This results in the html output:

```
<span  onclick="alert(' luxuriancy');alert('Reichtum'); " >Reichtum </span>
```

The html is displayed correctly

[image]

But when I activate the javascript by clicking on the `<span>` tag I get

[image]

So the the same text is displayed correctly in the html but I get diamonds after every letter in javascript alert box.
I also tried to put

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="iso-8859-1">
```

but it did not help.

Can you tell me what is going on . The alert box from the db is all right no diamonds issue... the variable $translated_word.

Comment: Are you fetching the text from a database?

Comment: The part that I am fetching from the db is all right, that would be the first alert box. The db is encoded correctly . The part that is the issue comes from the txt file that is parsed in a loop. The file is saved with unicode encoding. What is strange is that it is the same variable that I print and send to to javascript alert . It is correctly printed to html but the javascript adds diamonds after every letter. Now I will try to load a file saved with UTF-8 encoding instead of unicode to see if there is a change.

Comment: When I save the txt file that i load as UTF-8 I get the correct javascript alert with no diamonds after every letter but most of the html is now incorrect.

Comment: The screenshot looks like there's some strange characters in between the letters of the "Reichtum", so it's possible that the same characters are already present in the html, only invisible in the editor! My guess is that there's something wrong with the communication with the database and it's UTF-16. For debugging, you can try echoing the `ord` of each character of the returned string.